# Add .html extension to custom post type taxonomies

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, htaccess

I want to have the `.html` extension in the custom post type taxonomy urls. My custom post type taxonomy it is called "`product_cat`". I will need something like:

www.mydomain.com/product-category/product-category-name.html

Tried this one, inserting in `functions.php`, without success:

```
add_action('init', 'add_html_ext_to_custom_post_type_taxonomies');
function add_html_ext_to_custom_post_type_taxonomies() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^product_cat/([^/]+)\.html', 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

**Further tries:**

Also I've used the [Custom Post Type Permalink](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin and have played around line 559. Replaced the code from line 559 to line 561 with the next one:

```
$termlink = str_replace( $wp_home, $wp_home, $termlink );
$str = rtrim( preg_replace("/%[a-z_]*%/","",get_option("permalink_structure")) ,'/');//remove with front
return str_replace($str, "", $termlink.'.html' );
```

This will return the `.html` in the taxonomy view page url, but it gives a 404.

Comment: Just wondering, why? Is it for SEO? If yes, you should really do a 301 redirect to the proper page.

Comment: It is just a request from a friend. Don't know his reasons. This must be done dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your first attempt with using a rewrite rule it works

```
add_action('init', 'add_html_ext_to_custom_post_type_taxonomies');
function add_html_ext_to_custom_post_type_taxonomies() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^product_cat/(.+)\.html', 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

but you have _ not - had you noticed this as you give your example as `www.mydomain.com/product-category/product-category-name.html`

If its not a mistake it might be you have another rule conflicting with it? and also have you flushed the rules? You could check using the [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) plugin and also you can use it to flush the rules if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help. Yeah, I haven't seen the wood because of a tree :) It works now also for me like this: `add_rewrite_rule('^product-category/([^/]+)\.html', 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]', 'top');` One single issue: subcategories are returning a 404

Comment: Is there a separate parameter for sub categories or is it just product_cat=subcategory?

Comment: The same parameter also for sub categories, `product_cat`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a subcategory your testing with? Might be something to do with that subcategory conflicting with another rule.

Comment: `http://www.mydomain.com/product-category/parent-product-category/sub-category.html` from where `product-category` is the category base, as it shows also above in the desc.

Comment: Ah I see thats the problem I'll update my answer.

Comment: you have to add additional rules for each level of subcategory. it's important to note though that this is only half of the solution- you still need to filter term link output so WordPress outputs the correct link for API requests like [`get_term_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link).

Comment: See the updated answer the [^/]+ part of the rule means that only ?product_cat=parent-product-category would be passed through. And the rest would not match the rule hence the issue.

Comment: But its worth noting that will then be passed as ?product_cat=parent-product-category/sub-category so you'll probably need to do a replace or something depending on how you have the category setup.

Comment: It works fine both parent product categories but also product sub categories. Thanks a lot! I've learned something new, expecially about flushing, that new plugin and will need to learn more about `[^/]+` "part".

Comment: I can award the bounty in ~20 hours.

Comment: Cool thanks the [^/]+ simple means match while not / if you want to learn more about mod_rewrite you can check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html also the apress modrewrite book http://www.apress.com/9781590595619 is very good.