# Add .htm extention to a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, functions, url-rewriting, html

I need to add '.htm' to all my urls on a new site - client requires that, as I am converting a old static site into WP.

(I use [Remove Taxonomy Base Slug](http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/) to hide the slug of my custom taxonomy "topic" url.)

Now, I have a '.htm' extension on all pages, post etc. Now, I only need to add this '.htm' extension to my custom taxonomy archives. Does anyone have an idea of how this can be done?

I tried this:

```
/* Add Tax extension .htm */

add_action('init', 'add_html_ext_to_custom_post_type_taxonomies');
function add_html_ext_to_custom_post_type_taxonomies() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^topic/([^/]+)\.htm', 'index.php?topic=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

which I found here 
[Add .html extension to custom post type taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107854/add-html-extension-to-custom-post-type-taxonomies)

That gave me no change at all, and I did remember to flush permalinks.

Thanks :)

Comment: You have asked the same question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140497/add-htm-extension-to-taxonomies-or-all-entries-in-general-for-that-matter)

Comment: Sorry, you are right - though it was no the exact same question. I meant to delete that post, as It was badly written, and not actual any more. I think this post makes much more sense, and maybe can be useful to others, instead of the other post. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not a problem, just delete your original question. You can just simply edit your question, no need to start a new question. Enjoy

Comment: By "no change" what exactly do you mean? Note that snippet you tried seems like it would make `.htm` links _work_, but won't do anything else like changing how those links are _generated_ by WP functions.

Comment: Hi Rarst, by no change I mean that all the links in the custom taxonomy are not responding when I type in the extension on my urls in my browser. The site should answrer athenasdanmark.staging.wpengine.com/emn_afghanistan.htm and show the page. It does not respond, with anything else than a 404 :(

Comment: `athenasdanmark.staging.wpengine.com/emn_afghanistan.htm` doesn't match the rewrite rule you created. there's no `topic` slug in that URL, so no match.